# Joining the Allies Bug

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

On Historical-AI, for some reason factions keep joining the allies while already at war, without being at war with the same nations as the allies.

They also weren't guaranteed, and sometimes they even join the allies AFTER capitulating... is this a bug or can i at least avoid this? seeing this makes the game a bit annoying seeing whatever you do you always end up in a world war for the smallest piece of territory...